# How to save data in UItextView in swift in a notes format?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I am making a notes app in swift similar to the one on the iPhone. However, when you go to write you entry, I have multiple `textViews`. The `textView` works fine when I go between the `tableView` controller and the `textViews` area. I want to be able to save the data in the other `textViews` as well when a person goes to type a note or open their existing note. The code for the `tableview`(**ViewController**) and the `textViews` (**DetailViewContoller**) is down below. Thanks!

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var data:[String] = []
    var selectedRow:Int = -1
    var newRowText:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.title = "Notes"
        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNote))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        load()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if selectedRow == -1 {
            return
        }
        data[selectedRow] = newRowText
        if newRowText == "" {
            data.remove(at: selectedRow)
        }
        table.reloadData()
        save()
    }

    func addNote() {
        if (table.isEditing) {
            return
        }
        let name:String = ""
        data.insert(name, at: 0)
        let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        table.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        table.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        table.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        save()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailView:DetailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        selectedRow = table.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
        detailView.masterView = self
        detailView.setText(t: data[selectedRow])

    }

    func save() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "notes")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func load() {
        if let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "notes") as? [String] {
            data = loadedData
            table.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var text:String = ""
    var text1:String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var textView1: UITextView!
    var masterView:ViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        textView.text = text
        textView1.text = text1
    }

    func setText(t:String) {
        text = t
        if isViewLoaded {
            textView.text = t
        }

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        masterView.newRowText = textView.text
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you segue between the ViewController & the DetailViewController? You want to send data from a view controller to another? Add a screen shot of your storyboard.

Comment: Dear Kegham K, I can transition from  the view controller to the detail View controller by sending either clicking the addButton or clicking on an existing row on ViewController. @KeghamK.